# How to deal with lack of a certain resource?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

When you have a ressource's surplus, you can sell it automatically pressing `ctrl + shift`.

In my case, my farms need water to produce food. I must buy water manually each time it is needed.

**Is there a way to automatically buy ressources you're lacking?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to click on the bouton below and the factory will auto-buy the ressource from the market.

[image]

However, these ressources won't be purchased if the factory doesn't make profit. It will shutdown instead. In addition to this question, you can **force the purchase**, if needed, with the first button of the screenshot.